# DAX CALENDARAUTO function returns empty table when used in Power BI Desktop

Tags: dax

Doh, followed along with the calendarauto example from the video (sqlbi.com) but no dates produced.

No syntax errors. Using 07.40 - Moving average.pbix

```
Table of Dates = CALENDARAUTO()
```

works just fine.

Tried other pbix files as well. 'New table' button was used :}

The following is the code I created that produces no syntax errors and no dates

```
Dates (CALENDARAUTO) =
    VAR _FirstDate_CustomerBirth = MIN ( 'Customer'[Birth Date] )
    VAR _FirstDate_ProductAvailable = MIN ( 'Product'[Available Date] )
    VAR _FirstDate_SalesDelivery = MIN ( 'Sales'[Delivery Date] )
    VAR _FirstDate_SalesOrder = MIN ( 'Sales'[Order Date] )
    VAR _FirstDate =
    IF ( _FirstDate_SalesOrder < _FirstDate_SalesDelivery, _FirstDate_SalesOrder, _FirstDate_SalesDelivery )
    VAR _DateTable =
        FILTER (
            CALENDARAUTO(),
            YEAR ( [Date] ) >= _FirstDate -- 'CALENDARAUTO'.[Date]
        )
    RETURN
        ADDCOLUMNS(
            _DateTable,
            "Year", YEAR ( [Date] ),
            "Month", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmm" ),
            "Month Number", MONTH ( [Date] ),
            "Quarter", FORMAT ( [Date], "\QQ yyyy" )
        )
```

[PBI Community post for cash and prizes :}](https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/calendarauto-dax-returns-empty/td-p/3759101)

Comment: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/DAX-Commands-and-Tips/DAX-CALENDARAUTO-function-returns-empty-table-when-used-in-Power/m-p/3759159#M146657   
resolved, missing YEAR() function to match types